# Kubernetes in Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have not installed minikube in my local windows machine.I have only used kubernetes in docker. Docker settings checked enable Kubernetes.Everthing is ok. I created a Pod and a Service succesfully.Finally I need to an **ip** **different from localhost**  for accessing through browser.

http://I_need_an_ip:31515

What is  equaliant **minikube ip** when use **kubernetes in docker** for windows, without **minukube**?

Answer (score 1):

"kubectl describe node docker-for-desktop" gives you the internal IP address that the docker for desktop node is running on (see also [Minikube vs Kubernetes in Docker for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209870/minikube-vs-kubernetes-in-docker-for-windows#comment89466771_51213918) )

Comment: I assume you can't use localhost for your case as that means different things for pods inside the cluster and the outside. On activiti we've hit this with needing to provide a URL for keycloak that matches when used inside and outside the cluster (since it validates token issuer URL). See - https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/blob/b54c564163fe575bbfcab2f5d14b89c7c1dda3b8/activiti-cloud-full-example/README.md