# Unable to access minikube IP address

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am an absolute beginner to Kubernetes, and I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_o8dwzRlu4) to get started. I have managed writing the yaml files. However once I deploy it, I am not able to access the web app.

This is my webapp yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: webapp-deployment
 labels:
  app: webapp
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: webapp
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: webapp
    image: nanajanashia/k8s-demo-app:v1.0
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
    env:
    - name: USER_NAME
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: mongo-secret
          key: mongo-user
    - name: USER_PWD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: mongo-secret
          key: mongo-password
    - name: DB_URL
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: mongo-config
          key: mongo-url
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-servicel
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30200
```

When I run the command : kubectl get node

[image: > Blockquote]

When I run the command: kubectl get pods, I can see the pods running

[image]

kubectl get svc

[image]

I then checked the logs for webapp, I don't see any errors

[image]

I then checked the details logs by running the command: kubectl describe pod podname

[image]

I don't see any obvious errors in the result above, but again I am not experienced enough to check if there is any config that's not set properly.

Other things I have done as troubleshooting:

1. Ran the following command for the minikube to open up the app : `minikube service webapp-servicel`, it opens up the web page, but again does not connect to the IP.
2. Uninstalled minikube, kubectl and all relevant folders, and run everything again.
3. pinged the ip address directly from command line, and cannot reach.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please paste your service yaml file ?

Comment: @Libin did you find a solution to this? cause i have the same problem right now, when i try to ssh into the minkube then curl the ip:port i get a response but not from external sources. Thanks

Comment: @Tahtoh : I ended up moving to docker for kubernetes.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix this exactly, but after failing on the same tutorial, I believe the problem in my case is the netmask.  I'm on a typical home network with a netmask of 255.255.255.0, so, all my actual machines are on 192.168.1.x.  However, the minikube node address is 192.168.49.2.   That's not in the same subnet, making it unreachable from a different host on my network, though it is available from the machine that's hosting it. That, or there is a firewall blocking it, as I've changed my router subnet mask to 255.255.192.0 with no luck... (but I may need to reboot the host)

Comment: Specifically, the routing looks like
x~ ❯ route                                                                            jim@ubuntu 17:03:19
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp6s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp6s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.192.0   U     100    0        0 enp6s0
192.168.49.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-ee3b5f11d53e

Comment: The mask for the 192.198.49.0 address that minikube uses is 255.255.255.0, which I think makes it unreachable, though I now have my pcs adapted with a wider mask...  Not sure, but it seems like the problem if not the answer.

Comment: @Jim, man, I face the same question as yours. my minikube has ip: 192.168.49.2. so need to make some configurations to my local network to directly access it.

Comment: Note for the future: this question is off-topic because the console text examples are all supplied as images. It may be regarded as off-topic as devops questions are better on the Devops sister site (but this close reason is more contentious, as Minikube is arguably a developer tool). Ideally the images would be swapped for the text equivalent.

Answer (score 22):

Try these 3 options

1. can you do the `kubectl get node -o wide` and get the ip address of node and then open in web browser `NODE_IP_ADDRESS:30200`
2. Alternative you can run this command `minikube service <SERVICE_NAME> --url` which will give you direct url to access application and access the url in web browser.
3. `kubectl port-forward svc/<SERVICE_NAME> 3000:3000`
   and access application on `localhost:3000`

Comment: Tried, all 3 options. First 2 does the same, cannot connect to the web app. When the run the third command, I get an error. "error: Service webapp-servicel does not have a service port 30200"

Comment: @LibinJoseph could you paste your service yaml file here

Comment: @LibinJoseph can you try this ```kubectl port-forward svc/<SERVICE_NAME> 3000:3000``` and access on browser ```localhost:3000``` or access pod directly using ```kubectl port-forward pod/POD_NAME_OF_WEB_APP 3000:3000``` and access ```localhost:3000```

Comment: Both of those commands gives a blank page. The first command gives the error in console `E0319 20:46:13.845282    6660 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 3000 -> 3000: error forwarding port 3000 to pod c3cc7b66ddf40acb868a8f54161408a9cf2261c98ed94353b2304c8635208804, uid : exit status 1: 2022/03/19 08:21:26 socat[29438] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:3000, 16): Connection refused`

Comment: I had the same issue, as per my experience, most of the time this happens when you are on windows and used docker as minicube's VM driver, therefore 1st option didn't work. But 2nd and 3rd options worked.  thanks

Comment: The second option works for me. But the ip is different:
```
http://127.0.0.1:50521
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```
It seams that on Apple OSX things are running differently and this is a known issue, please view:
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14039 
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13788#issuecomment-1068640594

Comment: worked second case

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this still relevent or not, but maybe for future reference
If you're using minikube, and you cannot access your minikube ip (maybe because of some firewall or else)
You can use miniKube service and porvide the name of your service

```
minikube service webapp-service
```

minikube will then create a tunnel between your service and your localhost, and will open it in the default browser

Comment: This worked for me. Surprisingly it is showing port 60276 when in fact I configured `nodePort` as 30100. What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Ran the following command for the minikube to open up the app : `minikube service webapp-servicel`, it opens up the web page, but again does not connect to the IP.
Uninstalled minikube, kubectl and .kube  and run everything again.
pinged the ip address directly from command line, and cannot reach.

I suggest you to try port forwarding

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

```
kubectl port-forward svc/x-service NodePort:Port
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 with Docker-Desktop one can even do not need to use minikube. Just enable Kubernetes in Docker-Desktop settings and use `kubectl`. Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51209870/12501050) for further information.

Using Kubernetes of Docker-Desktop I could simply reach webapp with `localhost:30100`. In my case, for some reason I had to pull mongo docker image manually with `docker pull mongo:5.0`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on Win11 (or perhaps other OS) your minikube IP:PORT does not get forwarded for some reason.

The solution that I discovered is tied to Docker Desktop - just install the docker on Win11 via installer.

There is a settings option in top right corner (the gear icon) - in settings -> enable kubernetes.

Use kubectl as you normally would to attach your yaml files. Once the pods start you can access your front-end through: localhost:exposed_port

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 with Ubuntu 20.04 WSL, it worked for me by using:

minikube  start  --driver=**hyperv**

Answer (score -1):

I got stuck here as well. After looking through some of the gitlab [issues](https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/k8s-in-1-hour/-/issues), I found a helpful tip about the minikube driver. The instructions for starting minikub are incorrect in the video if you used

```
minikube start -driver docker
```

Here's how to fix your problem.

1. stop minikube

   minikube stop
2. delete minikube (this deletes your cluster)

   minikube delete
3. start up minikube again, but this time specify the hyperkit driver

   minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit
4. check status

   minikube status
5. reapply your components in this order by.

   kubectl apply -f mongo-config.yaml
   kubectl apply -f mongo-secret.yaml
   kubectl apply -f mongo.yaml
   kubectl aplly -f webapp.yaml
6. get your ip

   minikube ip
7. open a browser, go to ip address:30200 (or whatever the port you defined was, mine was 30100). You should see an image of a dog and a form.

Some information in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710171/minikube-ip-is-not-reachable) is useful too.

Comment: which OS were you using for running minikube?